# Show that if p is an odd prime, then $2(p-3)! ≡ -1 $(mod p)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

problem: Show that if p is an odd prime, then :

> $$2(p-3)! ≡ -1  \pmod p $$

I know that I have to use Wilson's theorem to solve this question but that's all I know..

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Wilson's_Theorem

Answer (score 2):

Another way of stating Wilson's Theorem is
$$ (p-2)! \equiv 1 \pmod p $$
Considered $\pmod p,$ how would you describe the relationship of $(p-2)!$ and $2(p-3)! \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; ?$

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Wilson's theorem ( p is odd prime):

\begin{align}(p−1)!≡−1 \text{  ( mod p )}\\
(p−3)!(p-2)(p-1)≡−1\\ 
(p−3)!(p^2-3p+2)≡−1
\end{align}

Since $p^2-3p+2\equiv 2$ (mod p )

$$2(p−3)!≡−1$$